# Randomised MySQL Query Validation against another table

Tags: mysql, join, random

I have 3 tables:

1. A list of "users" (uID)
2. A list of "questions" (qID)
3. A "questionsanswered" table which stores which questions have been sent to which users (qaUID and qaQID)

I need to do a randomised query where I select one random question and one random user, BUT not allowed to select previously asked questions so it needs to validate against the questionsanswered table.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can `cross join` the `users` and `questions` table, and use `not exists` to filter out the tuples that exist in `questionsanswered`. Then all that is left to do is to randomly select one row.

```
select u.uid, q.qid
from users u
cross join questions q 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from questionsanswered qa 
    where qa.qauid = u.uid and quqid = q.quid
)
order by rand()
limit 1
```